# Laravel: Alias not correctly written when using Haversine formula on Eloquent query

Tags: laravel

I have written this:

```
$properties  = DB::table('properties')
     ->join('addresses', 'properties.id_address_fk', '=', 'addresses.id')
     ->select('properties.id', 'title', 'city', 'price', 'postedat',
     ( '3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians  (-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) as distance') );
```

But on reading the Error notice, I am not doing embracing the Haversie query correctly when I write "as distance". That is, I need that alias in order to be able to filter afterwards: Here is the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '3959' in 'field list' (SQL: select `properties`.`id`, `title`, `city`, `price`, `postedat`, `3959` as `acos(` from `properties` inner join `addresses` on `properties`.`id_address_fk` = `addresses`.`id` where `propertytype` = house having `distance` < 40 order by `distance` desc limit 5 offset 10)
```

Here is why I need the alias:

```
 $properties->having('distance', '<', $radius)
            ->orderBy('distance', 'desc')
            ->skip(10)
            ->take(5)
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `DB::raw()` to make Laravel inject the string directly into the query without escaping.

```
$properties  = DB::table('properties')
 ->join('addresses', 'properties.id_address_fk', '=', 'addresses.id')
 ->select('properties.id', 'title', 'city', 'price', 'postedat',
     DB::raw('3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians  (-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) as distance') );
```

Comment: Yep that's normal. Try `dd($var)` instead of var_dump

Comment: I got the same long display. I think it is happening because I have the same name "properties" in those expressions
 $properties = $properties->where('location', '=', $location); I don't know, I had done a similar query with a Users table and it worked alright.

Comment: I have read that DB raw makes it vulnerable to sql injection. So, is my query then vulnerable?

DB::raw() is used to make arbitrary SQL commands which aren't parsed any further by the query builder. They therefore can create a vector for attack via SQL injection.

Comment: I found the reason of that error. The calculations of distance using the latitude and longitude data delivered 33 kms which was beyond the 25 I had set, thus no results, no results then empty object and empty object has no properties.

Comment: Okay. And no your query isn't vulnerable. It only is if you use DB::raw() with user provided variables...